# Ext Js Grid show First page records on second page also

Tags: extjs, extjs-grid

Ext js grid Initially showing first page records, its's great; but when next page button is clicked, request is going to the Server and server also returning second page data but grid is not showing second page content, its showing first page content only but Page bar showing that we are in second page.

My store is:

```
Ext.define('CustomCMS.store.RolesPagination', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    id: 'rolePaginationInfo',
    storeId: 'rolePaginationInfo',
    enablePaging: true,
    alias: 'store.rolesPagination',
    autoLoad: { start: 0, limit: 2 },
    queryModel: 'query',
    pageSize: 2,

    remoteSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'RName',
        direction: 'asc'
    }],

    fields: ['RId', 'RName', 'RDesc', 'RIsRead', 'RISCreate', 'RISUpdate', 'RIsDelete', 'RISActive'],
    idProperty: 'RId',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost:51157/ProductService.svc/' + 'RetriveRoleswithPagination',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'RetriveRoleswithPaginationResult.RolesDetails',
            totalProperty: 'RetriveRoleswithPaginationResult.total'
        }
    }
});
```

My Grid is:

```
Ext.define('CustomCMS.view.roles.Roles', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'roleslist',
    id: 'rolesgrid',
    alias: 'rolesgrid',
    disableSelection: true,
    loadMask: true,
    requires: [
        'CustomCMS.store.Roles'
    ],

    title: 'Roles',

    store: {
        type: 'rolesPagination'
    },
    tbar: [{
        text: 'Add Role',
        action: 'add',
        iconCls: 'book-add',
        handler: function () {
            Ext.create('RoleOp', { action: 'A' }).setVisible(true);

        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Remove Role',
        action: 'edit',
        itemId: 'rempoverole',
        disabled: true,
        handler: function () {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp("rolesgrid");
            if (grid) {
                var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
                var rs = sm.getSelection();
                if (!rs.length) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Info', 'No Employees are Selected');
                    return;
                }
                Ext.Msg.confirm('Remove Employee',
                    'Are you sure you want to delete?',
                    function (button) {
                        if (button == 'yes') {
                            //alert(rs[0].data.EId);

                            Ext.Ajax.request
                                ({
                                    url: 'http://localhost:51157/ProductService.svc/' + '/RemoveRole/' + rs[0].data.RId,
                                    method: 'GET',
                                    success: function (response, opts) {
                                        var res = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
                                        if (res.RemoveRoleResult == "1") {
                                            Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Role Deleted Sucessfully');
                                            //window.location.href = 'http://localhost:49393/';
                                            var grid = Ext.getCmp('rolesgrid');
                                            grid.getStore().load();
                                        }
                                    },
                                    failure: function (response, opts) {

                                    },
                                    scope: this
                                    //jsonData: Student
                                });
                            // grid.store.remove(rs[0]);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }
    ],
    columns: [
        { text: '#Id', dataIndex: 'RId' },
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'RName', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Description', dataIndex: 'RDesc', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'IsRead', dataIndex: 'RIsRead', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'IsCreate', dataIndex: 'RISCreate', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'IsUpdate', dataIndex: 'RISUpdate', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'IsDelete', dataIndex: 'RIsDelete', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Status', dataIndex: 'RISActive', flex: 1 },
        {
            header: 'Test Column',
            dataIndex: 'RISActive',

            renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
                if (value == "Active") {
                    return '<span style="background-color:green;padding:15px;border-radius:8px;color:white">Active</span>'
                }
                else {
                    return '<span style="background-color:red;padding:15px;border-radius:8px;color:white">Inactive</span>'
                }
            }

        },
        {
            text: 'Actions',
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            align: 'center',
            items: [{
                icon: 'images/book_edit.png',
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                    var RoleId = rec.get('RId');
                    Ext.Msg.confirm('Edit Employee',
                        'Are you sure you want to Edit?',
                        function (button) {
                            if (button == 'yes') {
                                //alert(rs[0].data.EId);
                                Ext.Ajax.request
                                    ({
                                        url: 'http://localhost:51157/ProductService.svc/' + 'RetriveRoleById/' + RoleId,
                                        method: 'GET',

                                        success: function (response, opts) {
                                            var employee = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
                                            Ext.create('RoleOp', { action: 'U' }).setVisible(true);
                                            Ext.getCmp('txtRId').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RId);
                                            Ext.getCmp('txtName').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RName);
                                            Ext.getCmp('txtDesc').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RDesc);
                                            Ext.getCmp('chkIsRead').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RIsRead == "Y" ? true : false);
                                            Ext.getCmp('chkIsCreate').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RISCreate == "Y" ? true : false);
                                            Ext.getCmp('chkIsUpdate').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RISUpdate == "Y" ? true : false);
                                            Ext.getCmp('chkIsDelete').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RIsDelete == "Y" ? true : false);
                                            Ext.getCmp('chkIsActive').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RISActive == "Y" ? true : false);
                                        },
                                        failure: function (response, opts) {
                                        },
                                        scope: this
                                        //jsonData: Student
                                    });
                            }
                        });
                }
            }, {
                icon: 'images/book_delete.png',
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                    var RoleId = rec.get('RId');
                    if (RoleId != '') {
                        Ext.Msg.confirm('Remove Employee',
                            'Are you sure you want to delete?',
                            function (button) {
                                if (button == 'yes') {
                                    Ext.Ajax.request
                                        ({
                                            url: 'http://localhost:51157/ProductService.svc/' + '/RemoveRole/' + RoleId,
                                            method: 'GET',
                                            success: function (response, opts) {
                                                var res = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
                                                if (res.RemoveRoleResult == "1") {
                                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Role Deleted Sucessfully');
                                                    //window.location.href = 'http://localhost:49393/';
                                                    var grid = Ext.getCmp('rolesgrid');
                                                    grid.getStore().load();
                                                }
                                            },
                                            failure: function (response, opts) {
                                            },
                                            scope: this
                                            //jsonData: Student
                                        });
                                    // grid.store.remove(rs[0]);
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    ],

    bbar: [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        pageSize: '2',
        store: {
            type: 'rolesPagination'
        },
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo: true,
        listeners:
        {
            beforechange: function (pagingtoolbar, page, eOpts) {
                //alert('I am');
                alert(page);
                //Ext.getCmp('rolesPaginationGrid').getStore().load({
                //    params: { start: 2, limit: 2 }, callback: function (records, op, ds) {
                //    }});
            }
        }
        //items: [
        //     '-', {
        //         pressed: true,
        //         enableToggle: true,
        //         text: 'Show Preview',
        //         cls: 'x-btn-text-icon details',
        //         toggleHandler: function (btn, pressed) {
        //             var view = grid.getView();
        //             view.showPreview = pressed;
        //             view.refresh();
        //         }
        //     }]
    }],
    //buttonClicked:function  (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
    //    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
    //    Ext.Msg.alert("Info", "name " + rec.get('RId'));
    //},

    listeners: {
        //select: 'onItemSelected'
        'selectionchange': function (view, records) {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp("rolesgrid");
            grid.down('#rempoverole').setDisabled(!records.length);
        },
        'itemdblclick': function () {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp("rolesgrid");
            if (grid) {
                var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
                var rs = sm.getSelection();
                if (!rs.length) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Info', 'No Employees are Selected');
                    return;
                }
                Ext.Msg.confirm('Edit Employee',
                    'Are you sure you want to Edit?',
                    function (button) {
                        if (button == 'yes') {
                            //alert(rs[0].data.EId);
                            Ext.Ajax.request
                                ({
                                    url: 'http://localhost:51157/ProductService.svc/' + 'RetriveRoleById/' + rs[0].data.RId,
                                    method: 'GET',

                                    success: function (response, opts) {
                                        var employee = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
                                        Ext.create('RoleOp', { action: 'U' }).setVisible(true);
                                        Ext.getCmp('txtRId').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RId);
                                        Ext.getCmp('txtName').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RName);
                                        Ext.getCmp('txtDesc').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RDesc);
                                        Ext.getCmp('chkIsRead').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RIsRead == "Y" ? true : false);
                                        Ext.getCmp('chkIsCreate').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RISCreate == "Y" ? true : false);
                                        Ext.getCmp('chkIsUpdate').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RISUpdate == "Y" ? true : false);
                                        Ext.getCmp('chkIsDelete').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RIsDelete == "Y" ? true : false);
                                        Ext.getCmp('chkIsActive').setValue(employee.RetriveRoleByIdResult.RISActive == "Y" ? true : false);
                                    },
                                    failure: function (response, opts) {
                                    },
                                    scope: this
                                    //jsonData: Student
                                });
                        }
                    });
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Please, try to reduce the code to a minimum working example. It would also help if you provided a working fiddle with your problem.